# Jquery-ui dialog vertically center bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-accordion

i start with an apologize for my English, which is not my native language, anyway, I'll try to do my best !

I'm actually using Jquery UI for my website content.
Like that :

```
   <body>
     <div id=accordion>
       (my content well formed for an accordion)
     </div>
     <div id=myPopUp>
       <span id=popUpContent> myPopUpMessage </span>
     </div>
   </body>
```

Here is my JQuery code executed when I click on a button in my accordion :

```
var popUp = $('#myPopUp').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: 'top',
            modal: true,
            buttons: [

            {   
                text: "No",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },

            {
                text: "Yes",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });
```

So now, what's the problem ?
My popUp is set vertically out of position !
When i'm looking on the top of my page, my dialog is set on the vertical center... of the total page, not of my view of the page.
Something else ... if i'm looking lower in the page, my dialog will be set at the vertical center of the page + my window view location. (I mean, if i'm actually looking at 30% of my page, it'll be set at 50% + 30% of the total page !)

I suspect some kind of incompatibility between Accordion and Dialog. (More accordion's tabs i got ... more out of position is my dialog)

I hope you'll understand my problem,
and if you don't, ask me for more precisions =o !
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I just found a tricky way to do that (or just to minimize the problem).

I added to my popUp an option : position {my: "bottom", at "top", of: 'myselector'}
wich 'myselector' refer to the tab content in relation with the popUp

thx anyway !

If someone know a real trick to do what i wanted, i'm free !